# Insert two pages from a pdf document onto one album sheet

Tags: pdf, pdfpages

I create my document in the landscape layout and I need to insert another pdf document inside this document, but it has a portrait orientation, so I need to insert two pages from the document into one of my landscape sheets at once.
Tell me how to do it

```
\documentclass[landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[12pt]{extsizes} 
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.8cm,bottom=1.8cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./k/} }
\begin{document}
\textbf{Questions are answered on the next page.}
\newpage
%\includepdf[pages = {1-111},pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{Answers.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `nup=2x1` option:

```
\includepdf[pages=1-2,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain},nup=2x1]{<pdf>}
```

From the [`pdfpages`](//ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/pdfpages):

> **`nup`**
> Puts multiple logical pages onto each sheet of paper. The syntax of this option is: `nup=<xnup>x<ynup>`. Where `<xnup>` and `<ynup>` specify the number of logical pages in horizontal and vertical direction, which are arranged on each sheet of paper. (Default: `nup=1x1`)

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed!